# ArrayList is not working as expected

Tags: java

(I'm still pretty new to coding)
I'm trying to make a Minecraft plugin that has a command so that a player freezes when the command is typed, but my ArrayList is acting very weirdly.
When I type the command (/freeze) the plugin sends a message to me saying that the target has been frozen. When I check the list with a piece of code that says it in chat (code below) it says it is empty. But when I do the command again, the function unFreeze, that requires the ArrayList has the name, still, works. But if I move and freeze myself that way, the name is added to the list and it works, even the code that checks the list and says it in chat says it is there, but even if I walk and the playername gets added to the list, the text that says that I'm frozen or unfrozen doesn't seem to get affected, it just toggles between the two, and the command doesn't do anything else.

Code for checking the list:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("seefrozenlist")){
        for (String s : freezeListener.frozen){
            sender.sendMessage(s);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Code for adding the player:

```
if (freezeListener.frozen.contains(player.getName())){ //normally freezeListener.getFrozen.contains(...)
    freezeListener.unFreeze(player.getName());
    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',player.getDisplayName() + "&e is no longer &b&lFROZEN"));
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',"&eYou are no longer &b&lFROZEN"));
    return true;
}
else {
    //freezeListener.freeze(player.getName());
    freezeListener.freeze(player.getName());
    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',player.getDisplayName() + "&e is now &b&lFROZEN"));
    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',"&eYou are now &b&lFROZEN"));
    return true;
}
```

Class that has the ArrayList:

```
public class FreezeListener implements Listener {
// was private, is public for testing
public ArrayList<String> frozen = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<String> getFrozen(){
    return frozen;
}

public void freeze(String name){
    //if (!(frozen.contains(name))){
        frozen.add(name.trim());
        Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(name).sendMessage("\"" + name + "\" Freeze");
    //}
}

public void unFreeze(String name){
    if (frozen.contains(name)){
        frozen.remove(name);
        Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(name).sendMessage("\"" + name + "\" Unfreeze");
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent event){
    if (getFrozen().contains(event.getPlayer().getName().trim())){
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("2");
        Location to = event.getFrom();
        to.setPitch(event.getTo().getPitch());
        to.setYaw(event.getTo().getYaw());
        event.setTo(to);
    }
    //For testing
    else {
        freeze(event.getPlayer().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to do? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to have it so that when i type /freeze <playername> the players name gets added to the list of frozen players, and is then checked in the onPlayerMove event.

Comment: How do you declare `freezeListener` in classes with first and second blocks of code (`onCommand` method and the one to add/remove player)?

Comment: There is an asymmetry in your code: you trim to freeze, but not to unfreeze.

Comment: FreezeListener freezeListener = new FreezeListener();

Comment: Also, In your code `onPlayerMove`, you are freezing every player that is already not present in the list.

Comment: @Chinmayjain It's added for testing.

Comment: But unfreeze shouldn't affect freeze and checking frozen

Comment: Try name.trim() in unfreeze. Even if it doesn't solve your problem, an asymmetric code can always cause problems in future.

Comment: @SomeGuy Is first and second block of code in the same class?

Comment: first block is in Main and second in FreezeCommand

Comment: I don't get it, but I'm pretty sure that the ArrayList is not the culprit.

Comment: also name.trim() didn't seem to help (the player names shouldn't have spaces)

Comment: i don't know what the problem is, im just guessing

Comment: both classes, Main and FreezeCommand have this code: FreezeListener freezeListener = new FreezeListener(); does this mean that i have 2 different instances of it?

Comment: How an object `freezeListener` in Main can share the variables of the object `freezeListener` in FreezeCommand? Either make it static or pass the object `freezeListener`

Comment: i instantly thought of that when i wrote that previous comment, it explains a lot why some classes find something and others do not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have few different instances of `FreezeListener`. The one which is used for adding/removing player is not the same that is read in chat with `onCommand`. You should create new `FreezeListener` once and use it everywhere. You should do something like that probably in main class:

```
FreezeListener freezeListener = new FreezeListener();
FreezeCommand freezeCommand = new FreezeCommand( freezeListener); //<- This listener...

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("seefrozenlist")){
        for (String s : freezeListener.frozen){ // <-...and this one are now the same listener and will share the list of frozen players
            sender.sendMessage(s);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can try to be more accurate if you show your main class.

Comment: FreezeCommand freezeCommand = new FreezeCommand( freezeListener);? Why?

Comment: To send `FreezeListener` to `FreezeCommand`, so the `FreezeCommand` can use the same listener as the main class (and your `onCommand` method). You don't have to send it in constructor, you can set it later with setter.

Comment: in FreezeCommand can i do something like: public void setListener(FreezeListener fr){ FreezeListener freezeListener = fr }?

Comment: Yes, this is how it can be done. Such a method is called setter. There are also getters (you have one in `FreezeListener` - `public ArrayList<String> getFrozen()`), but you don't need it in `FreezeCommand`.

Comment: On the other hand, you really want `FreezeCommand` to know which `FreezeListener` should be used, so IMO it's better to make a constructor that accepts a `FreezeListener` and sets the value of `freezeListener`. That way you are not able to make a `FreezeCommand` without listener.

Comment: I used the setListener thing, and it worked! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the object reference. Every time you create a new `freezeListener`, a new frozen list is initialised.

In your class `FreezeListener` try this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> frozen = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or you can use a single instance method as suggested by @Egan Wolf.

Whichever suits your need.

Thanks.

Comment: This is only half right. Declaring `frozen` as public doesn't mean it will be shared between instances.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I was suggesting was 2 methods: Either yours, or he can declare the variable static if he wants to share between instances.